# What are command line switches?

Tags: command-line

I tried google and nothing completely answered my question. What are command line switches, and how are they similar or related to environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A command line switch is an argument that modifies the command it comes after. For example, on a linux machine, the command

```
ls
```

will list the contents of the current directory. Modifying this with a command-line switch like so:

```
ls -l
```

will cause `ls` to list the directory contents in long format. So, `ls` is the command and `-l` is the switch.

Environment variables are variables provided by your environment for use by programs and scripts. An example on Windows would be the `PATH` variable, which is used for storing paths to commonly used programs.

Comment: Thanks. That helped alot!

Comment: `PATH` is the same in Windows and Unix, except for the separator: `;` in Windows, `:` in Unix.  It's a list of directories to be searched for commands in both OSes, and probably many ancestor OSes that came before both Windows and maybe even Unix.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple really. A command line `switch` (also known as an `option` or `flag`) are just that - options that you can use to modify a command.

in `ls -l` the `-l` is the switch.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser!

Answer (score 0):

Switches are just one type of command-line arg.  e.g. in `echo -n foo`, `echo` is the command name, `-n` is an option or switch, and `foo` is a non-option argument.

This question was originally tagged with [low-level](/questions/tagged/low-level) and [assembly](/questions/tagged/assembly), but apparently the OP didn't really mean that.  I'm going to leave the rest of this answer here anyway in case it's useful to anyone else.

---

You might find this article interesting: [Linux x86 Program Start Up or - How the heck do we get to main()](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html).  See also other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

---

In a POSIX system for example:

Command line arguments are received by a newly-`exec`ed process as an array.

The ABI determines exactly how a newly-`exec`ed process can find that array.  Typical ABIs, like [the x86-64 System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html), pass the args in a format that can be used (by the libc startup code) as args to C's `main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

The source of these args is an [`execve(2)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), which replaces an existing process with a new process running the specified executable.  `execve`'s function signature is

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

and those arg and environment arrays are terminated by a sentinel NULL pointer.  The kernel gets those args as input to the system call, and passes them to the newly `exec()`-ed process.  I highly recommend reading the Linux man page (which I linked) for more details, and as a starting point for more stuff to google on.

The `execl(3)` and similar library functions are just helper-functions to set up args for the `execve(2)` system call.  You can see this with something like

```
$ strace -f /bin/sh -c 'exec /bin/echo 1234'
execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "exec /bin/echo 1234"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x55932fc90000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efed2438000
... more system calls made by the dynamic linker
... then eventually some system calls made by /bin/sh itself (that you wouldn't see from /bin/true
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, ~[RTMIN RT_1], SA_RESTORER, 0x7efed1e82250}, NULL, 8) = 0
     ########## This is where /bin/sh  execs  /bin/echo, with an arg of 1234
execve("/bin/echo", ["/bin/echo", "1234"], [/* 69 vars */]) = 0
     # then the dynamic linker runs in the newly-exec-ed process and you see the same boilerplate
brk(0)                                  = 0x1408000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
write(1, "1234\n", 5)                   = 5  # this line tidied up to not include the 1234 on stdout, just the strace log from stderr
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fc63c0e0000, 4096)            = 0   # apparently /bin/echo really cares about tidying up before exiting
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So: **command-line args are 0-terminated C strings, pointed to by elements of the `char *argv[]` array, which is supplied by the OS**.

For more details on how to get at the command-line args from `_start` (the entry point) in a newly-execced process on x86 Linux, see Q&As [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035394/problems-with-accessing-command-line-arguments-in-linux-from-x86-asm).  I tried to find a nice canonical Q&A, but no luck with a quick search.