# Depth of parentheses in Assembly x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I make program in order to find maximum depth of parenthesis in String.

At first, I make C program with Assembly code, it works good:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char *s ="((abc) ∗ (ab+(ab)∗(cdx7)))−xxab((()))c";
int x;

asm volatile (
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
    "mov eax,%1;"
    "lea ebx,[eax];" 
    "xor eax,eax;" ecx - currentDepth, edx - MaxDepth
    "xor ecx,ecx;"
    "xor edx,edx;"
    "loop:"
        "mov al,[ebx];"
        "or al, al;" // check if end of string
        "jz print;"  // if end jump to print
    "cmp al, '(';"
    "je increase;"
    "cmp al,')';"
    "je decrease;"
    "inc ebx;" // next char
    "jmp loop;"

  "increase:"
  "inc ecx; cmp edx,ecx;js changeMax;inc ebx;jmp loop;"

  "changeMax:"
  "mov edx,ecx; inc ebx; jmp loop;"

  "decrease:"
  "dec ecx;inc ebx;jmp loop;"
  "print:"
    "mov %0, edx;"
    ".att_syntax prefix;"
    : "=r" (x)
    : "r" (s)
    : "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx"
);

  printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

But I have to make it in pure Assembler with .s extension, so i try this:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
  .globl main
  .text

main:
mov eax,offset expr
lea ebx,[eax]
xor eax,eax
xor ecx,ecx
xor edx,edx

loop:
  mov al,[ebx]
  or al,al
  jz print
  cmp al,'('
  je increase
  cmp al,')'
  je decrease
  inc ebx
  jmp loop

increase:
inc ecx
cmp edx,ecx
js changeMax
inc ebx
jmp loop

changeMax:
mov edx,ecx
inc ebx
jmp loop

decrease:
dec ecx
inc ebx
jmp loop

print:
push edx
call printf


data:
mesg: .ascii "%d\n"
expr: .ascii "((x))"
```

But I got segmentation fault(core dumped)
Maybe labels are working differently than in first program in c.
But I don't know, please help me.

### UPDATE

Thank you Jester
I edited label print, now it print out the result, but after that I still get segmentation fault.

```
print:
push edx
mov edx, offset mesg
push edx
call printf
ret
```

Ok, I remove it from the stack. Now i don't get segmentation fault, but after the result i have some rubbish text

```
print:
push edx
mov edx, offset mesg
push edx
call printf
add esp,8
ret
xor edx,edx
ret
```

Output:

```
2

f�f��UWVS������×
```

### Update 2

Ok, everything works right now, I use string from command line `./a.out '((x))'`
Someone can check that everything is ok.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
  .globl main
  .text

main:
pop eax #return address
pop eax #return argc
pop eax #return argv
mov eax,[eax+4] #argv[1]
sub esp,12 #return stack to the right position
lea ebx,[eax]
xor eax,eax
xor ecx,ecx
xor edx,edx


loop:
  mov al,[ebx]
  or al,al
  jz print
  cmp al,'('
  je increase
  cmp al,')'
  je decrease
  inc ebx
  jmp loop

increase:
inc ecx
cmp edx,ecx
js changeMax
inc ebx
jmp loop

changeMax:
mov edx,ecx
inc ebx
jmp loop

decrease:
dec ecx
inc ebx
jmp loop

print:
push edx
mov edx, offset mesg
push edx
call printf
add esp,8
ret
mov edx,0
ret


data:
mesg: .asciz "%d\n"
```

Comment: Your function has no ending, after the `call printf` returns it will blow up (you missed the `return 0;` from the c code). Also, `printf` needs 2 arguments. Learn to use a debugger. PS: `ebx` is a callee-saved register you need to preserve its value.

Comment: `ret` by itself is not enough, you need to remove the arguments you put on the stack.

Comment: You also forgot to zero terminate your strings. Use `.asciz` or `.string`.

Comment: Did you search SO regarding command line parameters?  There's a reasonable answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15048795/2189500) for example.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Did you read update2?